# iterating each character in every row of one column

Tags: r, regex, apply

The example of the column is `test <- c('apple #1930', 'apple #84555', 'apple A #33859', 'apple good', 'peach brand A - level 1 #8839', 'peach brand A - middle or not', 'peach brand A #2283')`

I want my result table to be something as:

```
 Name           Description     Number
apple              NA           #1930
apple              NA           #84555
apple              A            #33859
apple             good            NA
peach brand A     level 1        #8839
peach brand A    middle or not      NA
peach brand A       NA           #2283
```

I've tried `

```
findiffs <- rle(test)

newdf <- data.frame(
                    firststring = test[cumsum(findiffs$length)],
                    secondstring = test[cumsum(findiffs$length)+1]
                    )

newdf <- newdf[-dim(newdf)[1],]
```

but it doesn't give me the output I desire.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: this looks like mostly a text parsing task. try strsplit()

Comment: You need to provide more information on what constitutes a name and a description... E.g., "A" can be both columns, how to choose one?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that each column has its own delimiting character. So you might want to try something like this:

```
test <- data.frame(orig = c('apple #1930', 'apple #84555', 'apple A #33859', 'apple good', 'peach brand A - level 1 #8839', 'peach brand A - middle or not', 'peach brand A #2283'))


test %>% separate(orig, into= c("a", "b"), sep = "[#]") %>%  separate(a, into=c("aa", "bb"), sep="[-]")


              aa             bb     b
1         apple            <NA>  1930
2         apple            <NA> 84555
3       apple A            <NA> 33859
4     apple good           <NA>  <NA>
5 peach brand A        level 1   8839
6 peach brand A   middle or not  <NA>
7 peach brand A            <NA>  2283
```